# joining a table from a different database to a table variable

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I am working on a query that will join a table from one database to a table variable on a different database. However every time I try to run this, I get an error that says I need to declare the table variable, but it is already declared. Please help!

```
declare @Employee Table
(
    agt_responsible int, 
    employee_last_name varchar(50), 
    employee_first_name varchar(50),
    #_of_Compliments int, 
    DEBIT_Count int,
    DEBIT_POTENTIAL_AMT INT, DEBIT_TNT_AMT int,
    #_of_Value_Adds int,
    amt_of_Value_Adds int
) 

INSERT INTO @Employee
Exec proc_performance_AGT_roi '2015-05-01','2015-05-30'

SELECT * 
from omadb08.TANDT_EMPLOYEE.dbo.ADP_EMPLOYEE 
     INNER JOIN @Employee 
     ON @Employee.agt_responsible = OMADB08.TANDT_EMPLOYEE.DB0.ADP_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Comment: what is your error, and on which line it is occurring?

Comment: also you aren't working with just "different databases" according to what you've provided, but rather linked servers.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp you can look at select into

Comment: @Kritner the error is that I must declare the scalar variable "@Employee" but its declared because I just declared it at the top

Comment: An INNER Join of an empty table with anything will produce no results. Even without an error, you'll get no results

Comment: Try aliasing the table variable.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos its not an empty table. If I were to place a select from Employee', I get results so its not empty. Read the code you will see why its not empty

Comment: I suggest you format the code for readability then. Also explain how you are running the code - in SSMS, in a stored procedure? One statement at a time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to how queries are parsed, when you use the table variable in the join you need use quoted identifiers (either `[]` or `""`) or an alias so change this part:

```
INNER JOIN @Employee 
ON @Employee.agt_responsible
```

to either:

```
INNER JOIN @Employee e
ON e.agt_responsible
```

or

```
INNER JOIN @Employee 
ON [@Employee].agt_responsible
```

or

```
INNER JOIN @Employee 
ON "@Employee".agt_responsible
```

I would use the alias option as I think it makes the query easier to read.

Comment: And to think that I encountered this just two hours ago!